# A trigonometry based triangle problem

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In the triangle ABC below, side a is 10 units, and side b is 12 units. cos(angleACB) = 1/5. Find the value of cos(angleCBA).
I'm pretty sure that I should use the law of sines, or the law of cosines, but I need help as to which and how they can directly apply to the problem.
[image: Triangle ABC]

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Try law of sines (do you know it? Some background would be appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
(i) Use cosine rule to find side $c$ [using $a,b,\angle C$]
(ii) Use cosine rule again to find $\cos(\angle CBA)$  [using $a,c,b]$

The cosine rule is given by $$z^2=x^2+y^2-2xy(\cos\angle Z)$$ where the vertex $Z$ lies between side $x$ and $y$